# Android VpnService block packets

Tags: android, vpn

Edit:- i'm able to start the internet using vpn.The other issues is that now i'm receiving packets in my service in this piece of code of my **VpnService**.But i can't think of a proper way to block particular website.I've tried using name resolution using **InnetAddress** but that's not giving the expected result :

```
   **@Override
    public void run()
    {
        Log.i(TAG, "Started");
        FileChannel vpnInput = new FileInputStream(vpnFileDescriptor).getChannel();
        FileChannel vpnOutput = new FileOutputStream(vpnFileDescriptor).getChannel();
        try
        {
            ByteBuffer bufferToNetwork = null;
            boolean dataSent = true;
            boolean dataReceived;
            while (!Thread.interrupted())
            {
                if (dataSent)
                    bufferToNetwork = ByteBufferPool.acquire();
                int readBytes = vpnInput.read(bufferToNetwork);
                if (readBytes > 0)
                {
                    dataSent = true;
                    bufferToNetwork.flip();
                    Packet packet = new Packet(bufferToNetwork);
                    Log.e("loggg packet",packet.toString());
                    if (packet.isUDP())
                    {
                        deviceToNetworkUDPQueue.offer(packet);
                    }
                    else if (packet.isTCP())
                    {
                        deviceToNetworkTCPQueue.offer(packet);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Log.w(TAG, "Unknown packet type");
                        dataSent = false;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    dataSent = false;
                }
                ByteBuffer bufferFromNetwork = networkToDeviceQueue.poll();
                if (bufferFromNetwork != null)
                {
                    bufferFromNetwork.flip();
                    vpnOutput.write(bufferFromNetwork);
                    dataReceived = true;
                    ByteBufferPool.release(bufferFromNetwork);
                }
                else
                {
                    dataReceived = false;
                }
                if (!dataSent && !dataReceived)
                    Thread.sleep(10);
            }
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            Log.i(TAG, "Stopping");
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            Log.w(TAG, e.toString(), e);
        }
        finally
        {
            closeResources(vpnInput, vpnOutput);
        }
    }**
```

I'm receiving a packet in this format:

```
Packet{ip4Header=IP4Header{version=4, totalLength=40, protocol=TCP,     headerChecksum=14192, sourceAddress=10.0.8.1, destinationAddress=216.58.196.100},   tcpHeader=TCPHeader{sourcePort=39217, destinationPort=443,  sequenceNumber=800911985, acknowledgementNumber=823271551, headerLength=20,     window=29596, checksum=32492, flags= ACK}, payloadSize=0}
```

I'm using [THIS CODE](https://github.com/hexene/LocalVPN) for starter and unable to block packets.

Apps like [greyshirts no root firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=app.greyshirts.firewall&hl=en) and [mobiwool no root firewall](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.netspark.firewall&hl=en) works perfectly and they are also vpn based.Any suggestion is  most welcomed.

Comment: did you find any solution? Please let me know.
Stuck with the same

Comment: @Jeev no.still stuck

Comment: You mentioned you have tried using InnetAddress, but it is not shown here.  How are you using it and what are you seeing?

Comment: well i fetched the the destination address from packets and try resolving there names using InnetAddress but websites like olx.com etc are cloud hosted and the host name returned(from there Ip) was not proper.

Comment: If you have a list of specific domains/sites you wish the block, try pre-querying their IP addresses and match against those rather than doing a reverse query of IP to name.

Comment: Hi, I am having same issue and following same steps as mentioned above, had any luck solving this issue?